# Multiple search with join

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to search a rows of table3 that have id match in a table1 OR table2 with this query

```
SELECT T1.*, T3.*,T2.*
FROM (
    select id
    from table1
    where condition like '%field%') T1
inner join table3 T3
ON T3.id=T1.id
left join (
    select id
    from table2
    where condition like '%field%') T2
ON T3.id=T2.id
```

If in table T1 have matches but in table2 not, the query works fine but if in table1 not have matches but have in table2 the query not show any results.

Someone can help me?

Thanks

Comment: you have inner join between T1 and T3 and left join between T3 and T2. Change your inner join into right join.

Comment: Hi, thanks but with right join, shows bad mathces with nested querys. Look AdrianBR answer .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do left join to avoid excluding rows, and add a where with the condition you need FOr readability sake,avoid right joins and jsut use proper table order

```
SELECT T1.*, T3.*,T2.*
FROM Table3 T3 

left join (
    select id
    from table1
    where condition like '%field%') T1   
ON T3.id=T1.id

left join (
    select id
    from table2
    where condition like '%field%') T2
ON T3.id=T2.id

where t3.id is not null or t2.id is not null
```

Comment: with `where t1.id is not null or t2.id is not null` the query works fine. Thanks

Comment: some tutorial to improve table order in a querys?

Comment: just google relational algebra. The convention is to start with the leftmost table when writing. It's about readability and you being able to follow the logic, because otherwise mysql itself does not care about the order and writes its own execution plan

Comment: Thanks, If you have 1 minute see my new answer to the thread. Thanks